# When pushing an image in GitLab registry using jenkins, the error fails: Invalid repository name

Tags: docker, jenkins, gitlab-ci

If you manually use the following commands:

```
docker build -t company.domain:5000/root/dockerimages/image:tag .
docker push company.domain:5000/root/dockerimages/image:tag
```

That's okay. And in gitlab we get images. But if I run from jenkins, we get an error:

```
Invalid repository name (dockerimages / image), only [a-z0-9-_.] Are allowed
```

Comment: Please provide accurate details, I don't believe your real output contains spaces between registry and image names.

Comment: Has corrected. Extra spaces are removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the matter is in the difference of the docker. An obsolete client on the side of jenkins is not ready for multi-level repositories.

Comment: Installing Docker on Debian 8 from the Docker's repository https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-server-debian indeed solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must login to the registry before pushing:

`docker login company.domain:5000 -u <user> -p <password>`

Comment: docker: "login" requires a maximum of 1 argument.